# Create a query to get counts and other columns

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to figure out the best way to write this Sql query.
I need to get a total number of promotional emails a customer has read that were sent to them . So we have a table that store customerinformation, a table that stores their Login information and table which stores the links to the different emails sent to the customers and a table that logs the clicks

this is what i have so far.

```
Select Customer.CustomerId,
Customer.FirstName,
Customer.LastName,
Customer.email,
Customer.Phone
From Customer
Join LoginInformation
ON customer.CustomerId = LoginInformation.CustomerId
JOIN ProductLinks
ON LoginInformation.LoginId= ProductLinks.LoginId
```

Now i need to get the total click each customer has made which are in a click table which has the following columns

```
ClickID
ProductLinkID
LoginId
```

i need the following output

```
  Customer.CustomerId,
   Customer.FirstName,
   Customer.LastName,
   Customer.email,
   Customer.Phone,
   Total Clicks   ( this can be a sum of all the porductlinks every clicked)
```

using SQL and C#

Comment: Use Count() and GROUP BY

Comment: Please check out the FAQs about reputation http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 1):

You need this kind of construct. Note the 2 column LEFT JOIN onto Click

```
Select 
  Cu.CustomerId,
  Cu.FirstName,
  Cu.LastName,
  Cu.email,
  Cu.Phone,
  Count(Ck.LoginId) AS [Total Clicks]
From 
  Customer Cu
  Join 
  LoginInformation LI ON Cu.CustomerId = LI.CustomerId
  JOIN 
  ProductLinks PL ON LI.LoginId= PL.LoginId
  LEFT JOIN 
  Click Ck ON LI.LoginId = Ck.LoginId ON PL.ProductLinkId = Ck.ProductLinkId
GROUP BY 
  Cu.CustomerId,
  Cu.FirstName,
  Cu.LastName,
  Cu.email,
  Cu.Phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Select Customer.CustomerId,
Customer.FirstName,
Customer.LastName,
Customer.email,
Customer.Phone,
Count(ClickId) [Total Clicks]
From Customer
Join LoginInformation
ON customer.CustomerId = LoginInformation.CustomerId
JOIN ProductLinks
ON LoginInformation.LoginId= ProductLinks.LoginId
JOIN Click
ON Click.LoginId = LoginInformation.LoginId
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerId,
Customer.FirstName,
Customer.LastName,
Customer.email,
Customer.Phone
```